# Setting QWidget to maximize within parent in Qt Creator/Designer?

Tags: qt

I have dragged and dropped a widget within a parent widget in the designer within qt creator.

It has an arbitrary fixed position rectangle within its parent.

I want to modify it such that it will conform to its parents dimensions.  That is it should be "maximized" within its parent.

What button in the designer do I press to do this?

Comment: the "centralWidget" QWidget child of a QMainWindow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what layouts are for. See [this](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/layout.html) for an explanation.

I'm not particularly familiar with Qt Designer, but the general process is to create a layout (QHBoxLayout would work for you) for the parent widget, and add the child widget to that layout.

Another thing to consider is that, in your case, you could simply set the child widget to *be* the central widget of the QMainWindow:

```
this->setCentralWidget(theMaximizedWidget);
```

Comment: Is it possible to change the central widget within QtDesigner?

Comment: No, you can only do it programmatically. If you want to only use Qt Designer, just give the central widget a layout and then add the child widget to that layout.